# Enviar array al local estorage

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de enviar un array al local storage, cada ves que se hace click en el botón y el input tiene info se envía el elemento efectivamente al array en el local storage, asi:

```
["info antes de recargar 1","info antes de recargar 2","info antes de recargar 3"]
```

ahora si yo recargo la página y escribo algo en el input, todos los elementos del array se borran y crea otro array con la info nueva, así

```
["info nueva 1","info nueva 2","info nueva 3"]
```

como puedo hacer para que la info anterior no se borre y por el contrario se vaya actualizando el array que va quedando guardado en el local estorage asi:

```
 ["info antes de recargar 1","info antes de recargar 2","info antes de recargar 3", "info nueva 1","info nueva 2","info nueva 3"];
```

o siempre que se recarga la pagína se reinicia el array?

gracias por la ayuda

```js
var mydiv = document.querySelectorAll(".div_btn");
console.log(mydiv);

for(i=0; i<mydiv.length; i++){
   mydiv[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var parent = this.parentElement;
      console.log(parent.firstElementChild.innerHTML);
   });
}


var btn_local = document.getElementById("btn_local");
var user_name = document.getElementById("user_name");

var mi_array = []; 

btn_local.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var name_value =  user_name.value;
  if(name_value !== ""){

   mi_array.push(name_value);
   console.log(mi_array);

   var json_transform = JSON.stringify(mi_array);
   localStorage.setItem("usuarios", json_transform);
  }
})
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="user_name" placeholder="ingrese su nombre">
    <button id="btn_local">Send array to local host</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de ejecutar esta línea:

```
localStorage.setItem("usuarios", json_transform);
```

Está sobreescribiendo los usuarios existentes en el LS.
Para solucionarlo hay que obtener primero los datos e insertar los nuevos.

```
btn_local.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var name_value =  user_name.value;
  if(name_value !== ""){

   mi_array.push(name_value);
   console.log(mi_array);

   const users = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('usuarios')) || [];    // editada
   var json_transform = JSON.stringify(users.concat(mi_array));         // editada
   localStorage.setItem("usuarios", json_transform);
  }
})
```